# Am I required to have my Radiotelephone Operator's Restricted Certificate (Aeronautical) on-board the aircraft with me?

Tags: radio-communications, transport-canada

Is there a Canadian law or regulation which requires me to have my Radiotelephone Operator's Restricted Certificate (Aeronautical) on-board the aircraft with me?

This is what I've found so far:

Canada requires you to *hold* the certificate ([Radiocommunications regulations, Part V, Section 33](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-96-484/page-7.html#h-33)):

> A person may operate radio apparatus in the aeronautical service, maritime service or amateur radio service only where the person holds an appropriate radio operator certificate [...]

However, I can't find a regulation saying I need the piece of paper with me.

An example of the wording Canada uses in its regulations to say that you need to actually have the document with you is at [CARS 401.03 (1)(d)](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-96-433/page-75.html) (regarding pilot licences):

> the person can produce the permit, licence or rating, and the certificate, when exercising those privileges.

I can't find that wording or anything like it relating to my radio operator's certificate in the CARS, the Radiocommunications Regulations, the Aeronautics Act, or the Radiocommunications Act.

Comment: How else are they going to make sure you have one?

Comment: @user2168 *Whose* database? In order to verify my RTO license they'd have to call the FCC :-)

Comment: @user2168 The question of how the license is verified seems germane: If I, as a US-licensed pilot, fly into Canada I am required to hold a RTO certificate in order to use my radios in that country. I would get that license through the FCC (and my understanding is Canada recognizes it via some arrangement between the two countries that I don't want to know the details of - We probably sold Utah or something), but AFAIK they can only verify that by me carrying the paper. (I don't think any of this changes your question, but it may make the *answer* longer :-)

Comment: Seems simple enough to look at any wording in the CARs about holding or carrying or possessing a pilot's certificate to exercise privileges, and compare that wording to the RRTO phrasing.

Comment: It's a suggestion. I don't know Canadian regs or aviation law but legally speaking that sort of language ought to be interchangeable. The FAA is remarkably consistent when it comes to things like this and I imagine the CAA is as well.

Comment: ...which is why it's a comment and not an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to have the certificate with you on board during flight.

> The holder of a radio authorization shall, at the request of an inspector appointed pursuant to the Act, show the radio authorization or a copy thereof to the inspector within 48 hours after the request.

Source:[Radiocommunication Regulations, s 38](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/sor-96-484/page-8.html#h-35)

Comment: Could you include a more global answer as opposed to just people flying **in** canada, **from** canada

Comment: @BrianWheeler The question is tagged transport-canada, (and the question specifically asks about Canada) so this answer is appropriate to the question.  If you have questions about other jurisdictions then it would be appropriate to ask another question.  There are far too many different countries to try to answer them all in one Q&A.  For more info see [How should we handle country specific questions answers?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-should-we-handle-country-specific-questions-answers)